# Seeking learning resourses for OGC Filters or Filter Encoding Standard (fes)

Tags: filter, xml, references, ogc, http-post

When I am doing HTTP GET requests to GeoServer it is fairly easy, but when I need to do http POST request I need to pass XML formatted parameters in the body and for filtering I need OGC filters and filter encoding standard of OGC.

What are resources to learn it from?

Answer (score 2):

You may also find the [GeoServer manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html) helpful.

And, if you are converting from CQL then I wrote a [small utility](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/code/ogc/2015/03/18/Generating-OGC-Filters.html) to convert cql to OGC filters a while ago that might help.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the relevant OGC interface standards documents, so for Filter Encoding ~ http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter.